# Switching between cloned prefabs using a single game object variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Issue solved! I created a selectedCharacter variable in the headboard.cs script and signed the game object to it. Also did an Input.GetButtonDown method in Update() (which I had previously tried with the game object variable). Anyhow, the raycast worked and all clones can now be selected independently. Thanks for the responses :)

I'm having a little trouble switching between cloned prefabs within my hex-based board game and am wondering if anyone can help.

Basically, I generate my characters through a method that uses the same game object variable, so upon entering the actual game, only the last instantiated clone is still in possession of said game object, and it moves, which is great. However, I've been unable to reassign the game object so as to allow for all three characters to move when clicked.

So far I've attempted recasting and the `Find(object name)` method, but without any luck. The `Find` method does switch control, but to the first instance it finds in the hierarchy.

Everything I try returns:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ClickableHex.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/ClickableHex.cs:33)
```

Line 33: int CurrentPosX = character.hexTileX;

Any ideas?

```
   private void OnMouseDown()
   {

   Debug.Log("Clicked: " + hexX + "," + hexZ);

   gameBoard.go = GameObject.Find("Character(Clone)");

   character = gameBoard.go.GetComponent<Character>();

   int CurrentPosX = character.hexTileX;
   int CurrentPozZ = character.hexTileZ;

   //ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
       // if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
       // {
        //Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);

       // }


   if (character.isSelected == true && !gameBoard.hexTiles[(int)hexX, (int)hexZ].isOccupied)
   {
       gameBoard.MoveSelectedCharacter(character, hexX, hexZ);
       gameBoard.hexTiles[(int)hexX, (int)hexZ].isOccupied = true;
       gameBoard.hexTiles[CurrentPosX, CurrentPozZ].isOccupied = false;
       character.isSelected = false;
   }


   }
```

Any suggestions or resources you could point me towards would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Which line is equivalent to line 33 (where the error is)? IIRC, unity adds a space before "(Clone)", so make sure that it is not `Character (Clone)`

Comment: Hi R Astra, it's the line: int CurrentPosX = character.hexTileX;

Comment: This means that character is null. Perhaps the gameobject was never found (GameObject.Find failed) or maybe the gameobject did not have a character component (GetComponent<Character> failed)